# JW Player gives error when trying to play an mp4 video file from a virtual folder

Tags: html5-video, mp4, jwplayer

I have an web app that is running on localhost for now.

I have one flv file and one mp4 file in a virtual directory (these files are processed using FFMPEG)
I have JW Player set to run in HTML5 by default.

When I point the src to the flv file it plays fine.
But if I change the video's src to the mp4 file in the same directory it gives me this error on both FF and Chrome

```
The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported: http://localhost/files/john/test video.mp4undefined
```

What I am doing wrong? Please help.

Here is my code:
`<video id="container" src="http://localhost/files/john/test video.mp4" width="640" height="360" type="video/mp4"></video>` <-- gives error

`<video id="container" src="http://localhost/files/john/test video.flv" width="640" height="360"></video>` <-- works

```
jwplayer('container').setup({
'autostart': 'false',
'flashplayer': '../../../../Content/jw/player.swf',
'id': 'JWP',
'width': '640',
'height': '360',
'controlbar.position': 'bottom',
'controlbar.idlehide': 'false',
'screencolor': '#000000',
'events':
{
//all callbacks here
},
'stretching': "exactfit",
'modes': [
{ type: "html5" },
{ type: "flash", src: "../../../../Content/jw/player.swf" },
{ type: "download" }
],
'skin': "../../../../Content/jw/skins/Papon/Papon.zip",
'logo.file': "../../../../Content/jw/logo.png",
'logo.hide': false,
'logo.link': encodeURI('site url'),
'logo.margin': 3,
'logo.position': "bottom-left",
'logo.out': 0.33
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Under:

```
'height': '360',
```

Add:

```
'provider': 'video',
```

Comment: Ethan, I added that. But no changes in behavior & I get the same error. All I am trying to do is play mp4 files in JW Player. Why is that so difficult I don't understand. COULD YOU PLEASE HELP ME RESOLVE THIS???

Comment: Please provide a link so I can debug exactly what is happening, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still on a localhost. I just added a new .mp4 MIME type in my web app. After resetting and restarting I am not seeing any difference.

Comment: I can't debug this without a link at this point, so if you want a proper answer / solution to your issue, please put something up, thanks.